# Can I Use Smartphone Biometric Sensor to scan Public Fingerprint

Tags: android, react-native, fingerprint, biometrics

Can I use the Bio-metric sensor provided by my Smartphone to be used as a public scanner to scan and store them in my Back-end Server through API calls? The Libraries that I've found (in Native codes as well) uses the Fingerprint methods only to match it with the prints stored in the device via authenticate method rather than providing me with the scanned fingerprint data. My Question is, how can I get the scanned prints that I can save in my Server through API calls?

Libraries in React-Native :

[react-native-fingerprint-scanner](https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner)

[react-native-biometrics](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics)

Java

[BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt)

Comment: _"how can I get the scanned prints"_. You can't. Maybe if you use some external 3rd party fingerprint scanner. But with the device's integrated fingerprint scanner you can't get the fingerprint data.

Comment: @Michael Even by using the Native C++ code through NDK won't help?

Comment: Using native code doesn't give your app permissions that it otherwise wouldn't have, so no. Even the OS doesn't have access to that data since it's managed by a separate chip.

Answer (score -1):

Nice question but I don't see the point of saving the scanned prints on the server side. In my opinion, they are only meant to be used to authenticate the owner of the smartphone and for security reasons the constructors are not allowed to give those biometric images. Anyway I am interested in that topic is someone has a solution :)